# How to update a running AngularJs app?

Tags: angularjs, updates

I am developing an AngularJs app, which will run on `localhost`.

It will make regular checks to a central server, to check if the app itself needs to be updated.

This might be changed data, which is easy enough to handle, but could also be a changed `view` or `controller`.

Can I update a controller from within that controller itself, or will the file be locked?

How would I `reload` the app?

Perhaps I ought not to update the app from within itself, but have a "watchdog" app to update it? Even so, might I have locked file  problems? And how would I "reload" the app?

Comment: In my opinion browserSync is your best partner https://browsersync.io/docs/gulp

Answer (score 1):

This is the work of your task runners like gulp or grunt to watch the changes over specified files and perform the action. None of this is related to angular.js.

Follow these link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-auto-reload

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

This will help you.